# DynamoDB sub item filter using .Net Core API

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

First of all, I have table structure like this,

```
Users:{
        UserId
        Name
        Email
        SubTable1:[{
                    Column-111
                    Column-112
                },
                {
                    Column-121
                    Column-122
            }]
        SubTable2:[{
                    Column-211
                    Column-212
                },
                {
                    Column-221
                    Column-222
            }]
    }
```

As I am new to DynamoDB, so I have couple of questions regarding this as follows:
    1. Can I create structure like this?
    2. Can we set primary key for subtables?
    3. Luckily, I found DynamoDB helper class to do some operations into my DB.
        https://www.gopiportal.in/2018/12/aws-dynamodb-helper-class-c-and-net-core.html
       But, don't know how to fetch only perticular subtable
    4. Can we fetch only specific columns from my main table? Also need suggestion for subtables

Note: I am using .net core c# language to communicate with DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I create structure like this?

Yes

2. Can we set primary key for subtables?

No, hash key can be set on top level scalar attributes only (String, Number etc.)

3. Luckily, I found DynamoDB helper class to do some operations into my DB.
   https://www.gopiportal.in/2018/12/aws-dynamodb-helper-class-c-and-net-core.html
   But, don't know how to fetch only perticular subtable

   When you say subtables, I assume that you are referring to Array datatype in the above sample table. In order to fetch the data from DynamoDB table, you need hash key to use Query API. If you don't have hash key, you can use Scan API which scans the entire table. The Scan API is a costly operation.

   GSI (Global Secondary Index) can be created to avoid scan operation. However, it can be created on scalar attributes only. GSI can't be created on Array attribute.

   Other option is to redesign the table accordingly to match your Query Access Pattern.
4. Can we fetch only specific columns from my main table? Also need suggestion for subtables

Yes, you can fetch specific columns using `ProjectionExpression`. This way you get only the required attributes in the result set

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought to keep separate table but it does not satisfy purpose of NoSQL database. According to following link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html
it states that:
"As a general rule, you should maintain as few tables as possible in a DynamoDB application. As emphasized earlier, most well designed applications require only one table, unless there is a specific reason for using multiple tables."
What would suggest for my table structure. 
And could you give me example of CRUD operation in .net, if you have